# scrlttr2 and geometry: firsthead shifted to the right

Tags: koma-script, geometry, scrlttr2

I am using class `scrlttr2` of KOMA-Script with a custom page layout via the `geometry` package. Unfortunately, this results in a small horizontal right-shift of my header. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [fontsize=11pt,%%          Font size
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Type area
   paper=a4,%%               Sheet size
   enlargefirstpage=on,%%    Enlarge the first page
   pagenumber=headright,%%   Page number on the top right of the header
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Layout
   headsepline=on,%%         Line below the page number
   parskip=half,%%           Space between paragraphs
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Letterhead and address
   fromalign=right,%%        Positioning of the letterhead
   fromphone=on,%%           Phone number in the sender's area
   fromrule=off,%%           Line below the sender's area (aftername, afteraddress)
   fromfax=off,%%            Fax number
   fromemail=off,%%          Mail address
   fromurl=off,%%            Homepage
   fromlogo=off,%%           Company logo
   addrfield=off,%%           Adress field for window envelopes
   backaddress=off,%%         ... with sender address
   subject=beforeopening,%%  Positioning of the subject
   locfield=narrow,%%        Additional field for the sender
   foldmarks=off,%%           Folding mark
   numericaldate=off,%%      Numerical date
   refline=narrow,%%         Spread of the reference line in the type area
   firstfoot=false,%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Formatting
   draft=false%%                Draft mode
]{scrlttr2}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=16mm,right=20mm,bottom=25mm,top=23mm,marginparsep=0mm,marginparwidth=0mm,showframe}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{0em} % space before signature, in case you write bigger than 12pt :-]
\@setplength{refvpos}{20mm}%\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{285mm} % vertical footer position from top of page
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------


\setkomavar{signature}{Full name}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firsthead{
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}
\textbf{Name}\\
    Address
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}
\flushright
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Phone & xxx\\
Email & xxx
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
}

\setkomavar{date}{\today}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{letter}{}

\opening{Dear x:}


\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and a screenshot of the result:

[image: resulting screenshot]

How can I make the black rule in align with the text below?

Comment: Instead of using the `geometry` package with the `scrlttr2` class I  suggest to use `\areaset{17cm}{24cm}` which approximately set the margins you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in your code are two issues and a missing length definition:

1. Instead command `\firsthead` use `\setkomavar{firsthead}{` (I'm sure you got a warning about that!?), because the command is depreciated.
2. You need to add `@{}` to your begin of the table: `\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}` to get the text exact on the right end of line.
3. You need to add `\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{16mm}` because you used `left=16mm` in `\geometry`.

So with the complete code:

```
\documentclass
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [fontsize=11pt,%%          Font size
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Type area
   paper=a4,%%               Sheet size
   enlargefirstpage=on,%%    Enlarge the first page
   pagenumber=headright,%%   Page number on the top right of the header
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Layout
   headsepline=on,%%         Line below the page number
   parskip=half,%%           Space between paragraphs
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Letterhead and address
   fromalign=right,%%        Positioning of the letterhead
   fromphone=on,%%           Phone number in the sender's area
   fromrule=off,%%           Line below the sender's area (aftername, afteraddress)
   fromfax=off,%%            Fax number
   fromemail=off,%%          Mail address
   fromurl=off,%%            Homepage
   fromlogo=off,%%           Company logo
   addrfield=off,%%           Adress field for window envelopes
   backaddress=off,%%         ... with sender address
   subject=beforeopening,%%  Positioning of the subject
   locfield=narrow,%%        Additional field for the sender
   foldmarks=off,%%           Folding mark
   numericaldate=off,%%      Numerical date
   refline=narrow,%%         Spread of the reference line in the type area
   firstfoot=false,%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Formatting
   draft=false%%                Draft mode
]{scrlttr2}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=16mm,right=20mm,bottom=25mm,top=23mm,marginparsep=0mm,marginparwidth=0mm,showframe}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{0em} % space before signature, in case you write bigger than 12pt :-]
\@setplength{refvpos}{20mm}%\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{285mm} % vertical footer position from top of page
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{16mm} % <===================================



\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------


\setkomavar{signature}{Full name}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setkomavar{firsthead}{% <==============================================
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}
\textbf{Name}\\
    Address
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}
\flushright
\begin{tabular}{ll@{}} % <==============================================
Phone & xxx\\
Email & xxx
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}%
}

\setkomavar{date}{\today}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{letter}{}

\opening{Dear x:}

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! Just to point out, the lack of a newline after `\setkomavar{firsthead}{` (i.e., the `%` sign) is also important to get the text flush left.

Answer (score 3):

By default the pseudo length `firstheadhpos` is set to `\maxdimen`. This results in a header horizontal centered to the paper. But your text area is not horizonal centered to the page. So you have to set the pseudo length `firstheadhpos` to the same value as your left margin.

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  parskip=half,
  addrfield=off,
  firstfoot=false
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand*\myleftmargin{16mm}% <- added
\geometry{
  left=\myleftmargin,% <- changed
  right=20mm,bottom=25mm,top=23mm,marginparsep=0mm,marginparwidth=0mm,showframe}

\setplength{sigbeforevskip}{0em}
\setplength{refvpos}{20mm}
\setplength{firstfootvpos}{285mm}
\setplength{firstheadwidth}{\textwidth}

\setplength{firstheadhpos}{\myleftmargin}% <- added

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{signature}{Full name}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{% <- remove spurious space and changed syntax
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}
\textbf{Name}\\
    Address
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}
\raggedleft
\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}% <- changed to align the last column with the rule
Phone & xxx\\
Email & xxx
\end{tabular}%
\end{minipage}
\par
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}%
}

\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Dear x:}
\closing{Sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screen shot of the result]

Note, that I have removed the unrelated stuff and added some changes to use the uptodate syntax for the `firsthead` variable. With an uptodate KOMA-Script version (current is 3.26) you can use `\setplength` instead `\@setplength`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Now I just need to wait for KOMA 3.26 to become available in ubuntu.